# retrieve part of an API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I would like to retrieve the "gueris" information from this API : https://coronavirusapi-france.now.sh/FranceLiveGlobalData

Here's my code:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const async = require("async");
const await = require("await");

user = "";
pass = "";
msg = "Hello World";

url =
  "https://smsapi.free-mobile.fr/sendmsg?user=" +
  user +
  "&pass=" +
  pass +
  "&msg=" +
  msg;

console.log(url);

console.log(
  axios.get("https://coronavirusapi-france.now.sh/FranceLiveGlobalData", {
    params: {
      FranceGlobalLiveData: "date",
    },
  })
);

// axios.post(url);
```

this is the result :

```
https://smsapi.free-mobile.fr/sendmsg?user=94655605&pass=FXEDBUiGQvIgUb&msg=Bonjour toi
Promise { <pending> }
```

Comment: PS : I use Axios for POST and GET resquest

Answer (score 0):

The value you're getting back is a promise, which is a proxy for a value not necessarily known when its created.

To get the value of the response, you need to use the built in `.then()` method. Like this:

```
axios.get("https://coronavirusapi-france.now.sh/FranceLiveGlobalData", { 
     params: { 
         FranceGlobalLiveData: "date" }
     }).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data;
     });
```

Comment: I used your code, but I still have all the information... (I changed the URL of the API)

`{ results:
   [ { total_cases: 17919322,
       total_recovered: 11271688,
       total_unresolved: 5621090,
       total_deaths: 686011,
       total_new_cases_today: 166614,
       total_new_deaths_today: 3618,
       total_active_cases: 116580,
       total_serious_cases: 5479293,
       total_affected_countries: 213,
       source: [Object] } ],
  stat: 'ok' }
`